# WPF Wait for textbox to update

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I've got a WPF window that should update a textbox to tell the user what is going on then execute a bat file.
However it is just executing these files without updating the textbox.

```
 MainLine.Text = "Running for " + customer;
 DataInput.Text = "Running Data input.";
 ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "01_DataInput.bat");
 Mailsort.Text = "Running Mailsort.";
 ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "02_Mailsort.bat");
 SampleandRecon.Text = "Running sample + recon.";
 ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "03_SampleandRecon.bat");
```

Execute process is just a method for calling bat files i wrote

So i want the textbox to update and fully finish updating before running the bat file

Any help?

Comment: Turn ExecuteProcess into an `async` method (e.g. by letting it run a Task), then call `await ExecuteProcess(...)`.

Comment: What will this do exactly? Will it start the execute process off and continue with the rest of the code? because theres more code after all the execute process that needs to be processed AFTER execute process. Everything need to be done in exactly the order it is in the roce

Comment: might use backgroundworker and at backgroundworker completed event you can start whatever you want to do. To update textboxes u can use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    myProgressBar.Value = i;
                }));
at worker_DoWork event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your ExecuteProcess method async:

```
private async Task ExecuteProcess(string file)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // run file...
    });
}
```

Then run your execution steps e.g. in a async event handler:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainLine.Text = "Running for " + customer;
    DataInput.Text = "Running Data input.";
    await ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "01_DataInput.bat");

    Mailsort.Text = "Running Mailsort.";
    await ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "02_Mailsort.bat");

    SampleandRecon.Text = "Running sample + recon.";
    await ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "03_SampleandRecon.bat");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, just to confirm, if i put   `foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(Baseloco + "Batch\\").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                File.Copy(file.FullName, jobpath + "Batch\\" + file.Name);` after an execute process, it will execute the process first?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but await does what it says, it waits until the Task has completed. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to initialize a new thread doing the work and then use dispatcher.invoke to set the textboxes. like so:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        MainLine.Text = "Running for " + customer;
        DataInput.Text = "Running Data input.";
    });
    ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "01_DataInput.bat");
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Mailsort.Text = "Running Mailsort.");
    ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "02_Mailsort.bat");
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SampleandRecon.Text = "Running sample + recon.");
    ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "03_SampleandRecon.bat");
});
```

**Edit:**

As the possibility was stated that the batch files may wanted to be run parallel, i would suggest this code for better performance:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        MainLine.Text = "Running for " + customer;
        DataInput.Text = "Running Data input.";
    });
    ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "01_DataInput.bat");
});

Task.Run(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Mailsort.Text = "Running Mailsort.");
    ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "02_Mailsort.bat");
});

Task.Run(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SampleandRecon.Text = "Running sample + recon.");
    ExecuteProcess(Baseloco + "03_SampleandRecon.bat");
});
```